# Generate in the same class two graph with paintComponent(g)

Tags: java, swing, graphics

How can I generate 2 `paintComponent` **graphic g** from 2 different method in the same class?

I have 2 different data (`FirstTour`, `secondTour`) passed through my constructor and I would like for each tour generate a graph `drawLine` either in same `JPanel` or in two different panels.

Here is a look for my first method in `Draw` class:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {        

             final int offset = 5;   
             super.paintComponent(g);
             g.drawString("Tourlaenge: " + distanceFirstTour, 150, 15);

             for (int i = 1; i <firstTour.tourSize() ;i++) {
                 int x1 = firstTour.getAdress(i-1).getX();
                 int y1 = firstTour.getAdress(i-1).getY();
                 int x2 = firstTour.getAdress(i).getX();
                 int y2 = firstTour.getAdress(i).getY();
                 String nameAdress = firstTour.getAdress(i).getName();

                 g.fillOval(x1, y1, 8, 8);
                 g.setColor(Color.red);
                 g.drawLine(x1 + offset, y1 + offset, x2 + offset, y2 + offset);
                 g.setColor(Color.black);      
                 g.drawString(nameAdress, x2 + offset , y2 - offset);  
                 g.drawString("Start", 10, 10); 
             }
          }
```

Second Method the same as the first but with different data `SecondTour`

```
public void paintChildren(Graphics g1){

               final int offset = 5;     
               super.paintChildren(g1);
                g1.drawString("Tourlaenge: " + distanceSecondTour, 150, 15);
             for (int i = 1; i <secondTour.tourSize() ;i++) {
                 int x1 = secondTour.getAdress(i-1).getX();
                 int y1 = secondTour.getAdress(i-1).getY();
                 int x2 = secondTour.getAdress(i).getX();
                 int y2 = secondTour.getAdress(i).getY();
                 String nameAdress = secondTour.getAdress(i).getName();

                 g1.fillOval(x1, y1, 10, 10);
                 g1.setColor(Color.red);
                 g1.drawLine(x1 + offset, y1 + offset, x2 + offset, y2 + offset);
                 g1.setColor(Color.blue);      
                 g1.drawString(nameAdress, x2 + offset , y2 - offset);     
             }
          }
```

**Constructor**

```
public Draw(Tour firstTour, Tour secondTour) {
           //First Tour
           this.firstTour = firstTour;
           this.distanceFirstTour = firstTour.getDistance();
           // second Tour
           this.secondTour = secondTour;
           this.distanceSecondTour = secondTour.getDistance();

    final int width = 400; // Breite des Fensters
    final int height = 450; // Hoehe des Fensters

            JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(width, height);
    f.add(this);
    f.setVisible(true);                  
            }
```

Comment: Since each `Tour` is an instance of the same class, you could simply put them in a `List` or array and iterate over this in the `paintComponent` method using the same code logic to paint them

Answer (score 3):

Two components would probably be better.

Then all the painting would be done relative to (0, 0) of the component.

If you attempt to do two paintings in the same component, then the first will be relative to (0, 0) and the second would be relative to the size of the first painting.

In either case, all the painting should be done in the paintComponent() method. There is no need to override the paintChildren() method because there are no children.

Also, you will need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of each component to the layout managers will know how to position each component. Then you can just add your two components to a panel using a FlowLayout and the components will be positioned one after the other.

Comment: @mKorbel, didn't even notice. Thanks :)